# Accessing data of a cell in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, indexing, analytics, cell-array

I was hoping I could get some help using the cellfun function in MATLAB.

Let's say I have cell that contains 5 10x2 matrices, i.e.

```
C = {[10x2], [10x2]...,[10x2]}
```

However, I want a new cell that takes the first 5 rows across both columns in each array, i.e. I want

```
D = {[5x2], [5x2]...,[5x2]}
```

Is there a way to do this in Matlab using `cellfun`? I tried doing

```
D = cellfun(@(x) x(1:5),C,'UniformOutput',false)
```

But then this returned a cell that only contained the first 5 rows of only the first column in each array (and was also transposed) i.e., I got

```
D = {[1x5], [1x5]...,[1x5]}
```

Hopefully I explained this well.

Can anyone help? I think there's a simple way to do it but I'm new to `cellfun`. It seems useful though. Maybe there's an even easier way I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the definition of indices of the columns:

```
A = rand(10,2)
C = {A,A,A,A,A};

%//           here ....|
D = cellfun(@(x) x(1:5,:), C,'UniformOutput',false)
```

In this case you want **all** columns, that's why you use `:`. You could also use `x(1:5,1:2)` - in your case it's equal to `x(1:5,:)`.

---

```
C = 

  Columns 1 through 5

    [10x2 double]    [10x2 double]    [10x2 double]    [10x2 double]    [10x2 double]


D = 

  Columns 1 through 5

    [5x2 double]    [5x2 double]    [5x2 double]    [5x2 double]    [5x2 double]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, exploiting the fact that all matrices in the cell array have the *same size*:

1. Concatenate all those matrices along the third dimension;
2. Keep only the desired rows;
3. Convert back from 3D-array to cell array.

Code:

```
N = 5; %// number of rows to keep
D = cat(3, C{:}); %// step 1
D = squeeze(mat2cell(D(1:N,:,:), N, size(C{1},2), ones(1,numel(C)))).'; %// steps 2 and 3
```

Comment: isn't that overkill in this case? I couldn't generate a case where it would be faster than `cellfun`, and it's more complicated in any case?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Yes, it's probably overkill. But you already gave the easiest answer (+1 already BTW), so I was only left with this :-)

Comment: alright, I'm not used to the case where we both have answers and mine is actually the better one ;)